# Minecraft 1.14 on raspberry pi 3

Tags: minecraft

I would like to know how to get it, I have Minecraft 1.12.2 but how do I get 1.14? Is there a tutorial for it?

Comment: I managed to run 1.13.2 AND 1.14.2 on raspi4 with 4g.
See this post for more information:
https://lb.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=242585&hilit=Minecraft+1.13&sid=ac062758e5d6eaa865da38f2d42efa03

Comment: Relevant question: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100991/can-you-use-a-raspberry-pi-for-a-5-6-player-minecraft-server/101039#101039

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen I want to play it not run it

Comment: Isn't that the same thing?

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen Nope.

Comment: @FluxedScript can you please explain the difference?

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen I want to play minecraft on a version above 1.12.2 not run a minecraft server

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Java_Edition_hardware_requirements

So I think that is a solid no, because the pi 3 only has 1 GB of ram(didn't even check the other reqs)

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen it runs 1.12.2 perfectly fine

Answer (score 3):

The Pi3 does not have enough memory for Minecraft 1.14, I have had it running on Gentoo 64bit on a Pi3B+ but it only lasted about 1 minute before crashing.

A Pi4 may be able to run it once a 64 bit OS becomes available.

Comment: Would 1.13 work?

Comment: Yes, 1.13 is possible, I will do a tutorial once 64bit is available on Pi4. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNCQXd1QzAc&t=1s

Comment: Please make a tutorial on 1.13 and gentoo with microphone as I think people do it easier with someone speaking to them.

Comment: Have you made one?

Comment: I have a Pi 4 and the server runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Minecraft 1.15.2 and it works just fine. You may want to set the preset ram to 1.5 GB and the max ram to 2.5 GB in your startup script. If you would like to watch a setup video, [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBX-90NcAJo).

Extra: If you want to download a spigot server, [click here](https://getbukkit.org/download/spigot).

Comment: This question is about the client not the server.

Comment: Oh. It initially doesn’t look like a client question. Meaning “get” as in installing the server.