# Can you use a raspberry pi for a 5-6 player Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft, pi-4

I am trying to use a new Raspberry Pi 4 (with 4 GBs RAM) as a Minecraft server for 5-6 players. Would it perform well or is it just more worth my time to build a server.

Comment: You say you are trying to do this ... so what have you found so far, performance-wise

Comment: Apologies I meant to say that i'm looking into doing this, as in I haven't done it yet, was more wondering if anybody else had done it and what their performance was like?

Comment: Give it a try and don't forget to tell us. I used to use and olf computer do to this… 
A brand New Raspberry 4 with 4Gb of ram well cooled should be enough, i believe your connection might be a bigger concern

Answer (score 3):

According to [gamepedia](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Server/Requirements#Running_a_Dedicated_type_Server) you require 2 GB ram and a 
Intel Core 2 Duo for 5-10 players, so I expect your server to run great.

Answer (score 2):

i'm running with rpi4 4gb (allocating 2.5gb ram), runs fine for 4 people, although at times i'm still getting the "running xxx ticks behind error" in the console. I've got a 54Pi knockoff fan, which at keeps the temp from 40-45C. I've overclocked to 1.75ghz, running fiber optic connection, so far pretty good. will try to run with a few more players soon!